# Use a function to calculate measures in a list and add these to my data frame

Tags: r, function, igraph, mean

I have a list of graphs for which I'd like to calculate the average degree. Since it's a large list and the data will change over time I'd like to automate the process (and likewise learn more about R).
Unfortunately I can not wrap my head around how to write a function that does what I want, so I tried (and failed) with a for loop.

Here is an example of what I tried:

```
sld <- list(sd1998, sd1999, sd2000)
ld <- list(1998, 1999, 2000)
nwmetrics <- data.frame(row.names = ld)
nwmetrics$degree <- NA

for(j in sld){
    nwmetrics[1:21,1] <- mean(degree(j, mode = "in",
          loops = FALSE, normalized = FALSE)) 
}
```

This does add values to the data frame, but the values are all the same and do not compute the average degree of each list element.

From what I found by looking across SO the lapply-command would be better suited to my purposes. However, as mentioned above, I did not manage to specify a working function.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Provide your `sld`? Provide data with `sd1998`,sd1999` and `sd1998`

Comment: Vitali, thanks for the answer - I was hoping this question was generic enough to be solved w/o data input.

My sld list consists of igraph-objects; "degree" is a command from the igraph-library. Hence, the data behind these items are data frames on their own. I can export them with as_long_data_frame if necessary?

However, the data could also, as an example, be:
`sd1998 <- c(2,4)
sd1999 <- c(5,9)
sd2000 <- c(10,12)`
and the request could simply be mean() instead of mean(degree()).